# Where do the points go?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, reputation, up-votes

I asked a question on meta.english and I got 2 upvotes for it, but I wonder what happens to those points.

See, I'm used to sites like stackoverflow and meta.stackoverflow, where if you get an upvote on the meta, it counts towards your rep there, which is independent from the main site.

Not that I care about the amount of points itself, but since "rep is a measurement of how much the community trusts you", I do wonder how it is that upvotes (and I presume downvotes) don't have any effect on this meta.english site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta.Stackoverflow is the exception, not the rule (and for purely historical reasons to boot). The rule on *all* other metas (90+ and counting) is that you only get ghost rep that only counts towards badges and the like, but isn't displayed anywhere.

From the ["FAQ" link](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) at the top of this very page:

> Reputation here is entirely derived from the main website; your reputation is the same here as it is there, synchronized hourly. Votes here do not affect your reputation in any way. However, you can earn unique badges here on the meta site.

There's a question or five on MSO, too. E.g. [How does reputation between the main site and its meta work on SE 2.0?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56172/how-does-reputation-between-the-main-site-and-its-meta-work-on-se-2-0)

Comment: Is there a reason why upvotes on Meta aren't counted?